# Compactness theorem for first order language, constructive proof

Tags: constructive-mathematics

**Definition (satisfiability)**: a set $\Gamma$ of formulas of a first order language is satisfiable if there exist a structure $S$, a Boolean algebra $B$ and an evaluation function $V$ such that $V(C)=1_B$ for every formula $C \in \Gamma$.

**Theorem (Compactness)**: a set $\Gamma$ of formulas of a first order language is satisfiable if and only if every finite subset of $\Gamma$ is satisfiable.

I tried to prove the Compactness theorem in a constructive way but I didn't succeed, so now I wonder if the Compactness theorem constructively implies some other statement that cannot be proved in constructive mathematics (an intuitionistic taboo).
Can someone help me?

Comment: Not quite duplicate, but I think answers there answer your question too? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/632394/659499 (compactness is equal to weak Konig's lemma, so can't be proven constructively)

Comment: Interesting! How can be constructively proved that the compactness theorem implies the weak Konig's lemma?